# Autolayout of table view with static cell table view

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistoryboard

[image]

I have tableviewcontroller class with static tableview cell. Please check above image. Continue as guest user button I would like to be as from 10 px from bottom of every device. I can do it using fixed layout of table view. But Storyboard is not allowing me to set layout constraints. Any idea?

Comment: If you don't need this button to scroll with all content you put it as `UITableView` sibling and align button with bottom layout guide.

Comment: But my class is not subclass of UIViewController it's UITableViewcontroller's subalss as I am using static cell.@Ossir

Comment: Good point, Susim. All I can think of is you can attach this view to some table view superview, but that's a nasty hack anyway and you need to manually remove it when this screen disappear.

Comment: One more way, which I have not tested either, you probably can add big enough empty and transparent cell and add section footer with this "Continue..." button. Section footer sticks to bottom and will be visible all the time.

Comment: So If I think your second option to add a transparent cell but what will be height (Constraint) according to different devices dynamic height? Can you please do more light on concept? I am also thinking @Ossir

Comment: I am sorry I confused you, I talked about that http://take.ms/O5ez9. Tho static cells does not support custom (like with button) section header/footer, only text. If you can move to dynamic prototypes you can do that in code quite easy)